# Kendo UI Drawing API export PDF splits html table too soon, generating an useless empty space on the page

Tags: javascript, pdf, dom, kendo-ui, export-to-pdf

I am using the Kendo UI Drawing API to export a simple html table to PDF.

Since default font size is huge, I apply a new font size to the whole container div and its children, as per the official Kendo UI documentation (found in **kendoui.io/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#customizing-the-looks**).

The problem is that reducing font size exports my table splitted at a wrong height, resulting in unnecesary white space, as you can see here:

- [Without reducing font size (pdf file)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24887772/stackoverflow/kendo-daw-pdf-splits-wrong/pdf-defaultfonts.pdf)
- [With a reduced font size (pdf file)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24887772/stackoverflow/kendo-daw-pdf-splits-wrong/pdf-smallfonts.pdf)

Do you guys know why this might be happening? I already tried:

1. Different margin sizes
2. Different forcePageBreak values
3. Different paperSizes (although I am required to use A4 size)

Thank you for your attention. I hope you can help me with this issue.

I have included a snippet with the very basic JS, CSS and HTML just in case you need to see it:

```js
 function getPDF(selector, nro, dateC) { 
  kendo.drawing.drawDOM(
   $(selector),
   { 
    forcePageBreak: "-",
    paperSize: "A4",
    margin: "0cm",
    multiPage: true
   }).then(function(group) {
    //Render the result as a PDF file
    return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group);
   }).done(function(data) {    
    //Save the PDF file
    kendo.saveAs({
     dataURI: data,
     fileName: "filename.pdf"
    });
   });
 }
```

```css
   .k-pdf-export *{
     font-size: 6pt;
     font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
   }
   .k-pdf-export h5 {
     border: none;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     font-weight:bold;
     margin-bottom:5px;
   }
   .k-pdf-export .configuration-summary .quote-total td{
   font-weight:bold;
   }
   .k-pdf-export strong{
    width:100px;
   }
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header class="main-header">
   <section class="header"></section>
   <section class="main-menu">
    <div class="container" id="navmenu"> 
     <ul class="main-nav"></ul>  
    </div>
   </section>
  </header>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="container">
    <section class="content">     
     <div class="container">
      <section class="content">
       <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="section-heading">
         <h3>Title</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="printable" class="row service-configuration configuration-summary service-quote">
         <div class="col-sm-12 main-column">
          <div class="white-space overf">
           <div class="quote-header">
            <hr class="blankspace-10">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6 billing-information">
              <h5>Information</h5>
              <p>
               <strong>Sit dolor</strong> <i>Lorem Ipsum</i>
               <br>
               <strong>Sit dolor</strong> <i>Lorem Ipsum</i>
               <br>
               <strong>Sit dolor</strong> <i>Lorem Ipsum</i>
               <br>

               <strong>Sit dolor</strong> <i>Lorem Ipsum</i>
              </p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6 order-information">
              <h5>Details</h5>
              <p>
               <strong>Sit dolor</strong>Lorem Ipsum
               <br>
               <strong>Sit dolor</strong>Lorem Ipsum
               <br>
               <strong>Sit dolor</strong>Lorem Ipsum
               <br> <strong>Sit dolor</strong>Lorem Ipsum
               <br>
              </p>
             </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="blankspace-40">
            <h5 class="quote-details-title">Table</h5>
            <div class="table loosetext">
             <table>
              <thead class="forcenowrap">
               <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Field 2</th>
                <th class="qty">Field 3</th>
                <th class="price">Field 4</th>
               </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="addon-category">Suspendisse sed ex tristique</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique
                </td>
                <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis odio, eget malesuada neque.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">494.00</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="addon-category">Suspendisse sed ex tristique</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique
                </td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">25.25</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique
                </td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">125.88</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique
                </td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">297.88</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique</td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis. </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">563.73</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique
                </td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">238.36</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique
                </td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">63.32</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                <td class="sku">Suspendisse sed ex tristique</td>
                <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vitae sagittis.
                </td>
                <td class="qty">1</td>
                <td class="price"><span class="price">1,013.56</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot class="quote-total">
               <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3">Value <span class="price">999.99</span>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </tfoot>
             </table>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </section>
     </div>
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some tests I managed to overcome this issue. This is what I modified in my code:

- Set width and height of the element being exported to the equivalent of an A4 page, in inches (meaning, set `width: 7in` and `height: 9.25in`). This was the one change that made everything fit.
- Set `"landscape : false"` inside the drawing function.
- Set `"border:none"` and `"overflow:initial"` for some containing divs.
- Change the element being targeted for exporting (so instead of a div with classes and defined css, it looks for a generic container div).

I am not sure about which one solved my problem! But I hope it solves someone else's too.